# How do I get rid of this weed that is outgrowing my hen and chicken

Tags: weeds

I tried to remove it manually but it keeps growing back

- blue arrow -weed to get rid of
- red arrows -hen and chicks+their flowers(dying flowers)
- green arrow -some ground cover that should not be there

[image]

<sub>edits must be least 6 characters</sub>

Comment: You seem to have several species of plants (plus some flowers that look more like incredibly cut glass than plants) in the photo. Can you edit the photo to point out the plant you don't want? Also, since I'm dying of curiosity, what are those flower-like things? Alternatively, add a few more photos.

Comment: ok I update the picture and the question please read the explanations

Comment: For what it's worth, the weed appears to be wood sorrel.

Comment: yes it seems to be that one, it makes yellow flowers

Comment: @EscapedLunatic - the flower-like things are the sempervivum flowers. They are rather alien-looking when you see them in person.

Comment: @Jurp - Thanks! I Looked them up and now the question makes a lot more sense (I'd been wondering how any of the plants shown could inconvenience chickens ).  Now that I know these exist, I'll be hunting for a variety that can grow well here in Southern China.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best, but not easiest, way to remove the wood sorrel is to dig up a shovelful of the area - sempervivum (hens and chicks), wood sorrel, and anything else that's growing there. Take the shovelful of soil to a separate area, remove the sempervivums (just keep the roots, not the soil) and set aside, then remove the weeds and discard them. Do this for the entire area, then replace the now weed-free soil and replant the sempervivums. It's essential that you get the entire root system of the wood sorrel or it will return.

Note: the hens and chicks that have bloomed will die, so there's no need to replant them.

Answer (score 0):

Your photo shows a lot of [Oxalis corniculata L.](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/oxalis-corniculata/) which I grow as an edible plant. Often, they perform better under poor conditions in the lack of competition from larger plants.

[Hens and chicks (Sempervivum tectorum)](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/cacti-succulents/hens-chicks/growing-hens-and-chicks.htm) on the other hand grows well under challenging conditions like among hot and dry stones almost without any soil.

To get rid of annoying weed you will have to arrange an [alpine garden](https://horticulture.co.uk/how-to-make-an-alpine-garden/), which only allows your alpine plants to survive.

Answer (score 0):

I have *Oxalis corniculata* (creeping woodsorrel) on my allotment. It's a bit of a nuisance. If you can't spot treat the woodsorrel with Roundup, remove and temporarily transplant the sempervivums you want to keep. Spray the woodsorrel with Roundup (carefully - follow all instructions). Wait at least seven days before replanting the sempervivum. Water as necessary until established. Hand weed or spot treat any reappearing woodsorrel.